# Is there a way to load an object in Hibernate without writing a query or having an ID?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, persist

I can persist an object into the DB from Java as such:

Table Person:

```
varchar name  
varchar groupID  
varchar emailAddress  
key on (name, groupID)
```

And in Java

```
Person foo = new Person("dhackner", "3");  
session.persist(foo);
```

The two arguments make up the key. In this case, name and groupID are the unique key in the DB, and thus sufficient to distinctly identify any particular row in the table (can have multiple "dhackner" entries, multiple "group 3" entries, but only one "dhackner, group 3" entry).

Assuming correct setup, that code will successfully result in

```
    name | groupID | emailAddress  
dhackner |       3 |           ""
```

I would like to be able to do the reverse of that without writing a query or using any autogenerated IDs:

Table Person:

```
    name | groupID | emailAddress  
dhackner |       3 |  "something"  
dhackner |       4 |     "foobar"  
   other |       3 |     "barfoo"
```

In Java:

```
Person foo = new Person("dhackner", "3");  
foo.load(); // something like this
Assert.assertEquals(foo.getEmailAddress(), "something");
```

Comment: I believe you are allowed natural keys under some conditions. Is that what you mean? Or generally on a unique field? And you can of course always abstract away the query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is, it is called [query by example](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-examples) it is pretty straightforward in Hibernate:

```
Person foo = new Person("dhackner", "3");
foo = session.createCriteria(Person.class).add(Example.create(foo)).uniqueResult();
Assert.assertEquals(foo.getEmailAddress(), "something");
```